# Updating a table when clicking on an element from another table

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I need to show elements on a table depending on the element (Person) clicked on another table. The problem is that, using a Service, if the user clicks on two elements of the first table very quickly, the data of the two elements is showed in the table, and I only want to show the data from the last one clicked. Hope you can help me.

Here is my code:

```
personTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
            (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                try {
                    contactoTable.setPlaceholder(new Label("Cargando..."));
                    showPersonDetails(newValue);
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PersonOverviewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            });
```

And showPersonDatails:

```
 contactoTable.setVisible(true);
        contactoTable.getItems().clear();

        firstNameLabel.setText(person.getFirstName());
        lastNameLabel.setText(person.getLastName());
        mailLabel.setText(person.getMail());
        phoneLabel.setText(person.getPhone());
        descriptionLabel.setText(person.getDescription());

        service = new Service<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<Void> createTask() {
                return new Task<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void call() throws Exception {
                        //Background work 
                        DBManager db = new DBManager();
                        String query = "SELECT * FROM eventos";
                        ResultSet r = db.executeSelect(query);
                        contactoTable.getItems().clear();
                        contactoData.clear();

                        while (r.next()) {
                            String q = "SELECT * FROM " + r.getString("Nombre").replace(" ", "_") + " WHERE Nombre = '" + person.getFirstName() + "' AND Apellidos = '" + person.getLastName() + "' AND Correo = '" + person.getMail() + "'";
                            ResultSet result = db.executeSelect(q);

                            while (result.next()) {
                                contactoData.add(new Row(r.getString("Nombre"), result.getString("Asistencia")));
                            }
                        }

                        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            try {
                                //FX Stuff done here
                                contactoTable.setPlaceholder(new Label("No invitado a ningún evento"));
                                contactoTable.setItems(contactoData);

                            } finally {
                                latch.countDown();

                            }
                        });
                        latch.await();
                        //Keep with the background work
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
        };

        service.start();
```

Comment: please create a SSCCE that does not talk to a database

Comment: What is the purpose of making the task wait for the UI to be updated? This seems redundant, especially since the task has no more work to do and is going to exit anyway.

Comment: Previously I had code there. But it doesn't affect the task functionality. I mean, the program does the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the same data list (`contactoData`) from multiple threads, with apparently no synchronization on the list. If the user selects two different items in rapid succession, you launch a service for each one, each service running its task in a different thread. Consequently you have no control over the order the two different threads perform their (multiple) manipulations on `contactoData`. For example, it is possible (even probable) that the order for two services executing asynchronously is:

1. First service clears the list
2. Second service clears the list
3. First service adds elements to the list
4. Second service adds elements to the list

and in this case the list contains elements generated by both services, not just one of them.

So you should have your tasks operate on, and return, a new list they create. Then process that list on the FX Application Thread.

It's also not clear why you need a service here, as you only seem to ever use each service once. You may as well just use a task directly.

You also probably want to ensure that the last selection is the one displayed. Since the tasks are running asynchronously, it's possible that if two tasks were started in quick succession, the second would complete before the first. This would result in the second selection being displayed, and then the first selection replacing it. You can avoid this by doing the UI update in an `onSucceeded` handler, and canceling any current task when you start a new one (thus preventing the currently-executing task from invoking its `onSucceeded` handler).

Finally, it's really not clear to me why you are making the task wait until the UI is updated.

Here is an updated version of your code:

```
private Task<List<Row>> updateContactTableTask ;

// ...

private void showPersonDetails(Person person) {

    contactoTable.getItems().clear();

    firstNameLabel.setText(person.getFirstName());
    lastNameLabel.setText(person.getLastName());
    mailLabel.setText(person.getMail());
    phoneLabel.setText(person.getPhone());
    descriptionLabel.setText(person.getDescription());


    if (updateContactTableTask != null && updateContactTableTask.isRunning()) {
        updateContactTableTask.cancel();
    }

    updateContactTableTask = new Task<List<Row>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<Row> call() throws Exception {

            List<Row> resultList = new ArrayList<>() ;

            //Background work 
            DBManager db = new DBManager();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM eventos";
            ResultSet r = db.executeSelect(query);

            // quit if we got canceled here...
            if (isCancelled()) {
                return resultList;
            }

            while (r.next() && ! isCancelled()) {

                // Note: building a query like this is inherently unsafe
                // You should use a PreparedStatement in your DBManager class instead
                String q = "SELECT * FROM " + r.getString("Nombre").replace(" ", "_") + " WHERE Nombre = '" + person.getFirstName() + "' AND Apellidos = '" + person.getLastName() + "' AND Correo = '" + person.getMail() + "'";
                ResultSet result = db.executeSelect(q);

                while (result.next()) {
                    resultList.add(new Row(r.getString("Nombre"), result.getString("Asistencia")));
                }

            }

            return resultList ;
        }
    };

    updateContactTableTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
        // not really clear you still need contactoData, but if you do:
        contactoData.setAll(updateContactTableTask.getValue());
        contactoTable.setPlaceholder(new Label("No invitado a ningún evento"));
        contactoTable.setItems(contactoData);
    });

    updateContactTableTask.setOnFailed(e -> {
        // handle database errors here...
    });

    new Thread(updateContactTableTask).start();
}
```

As an aside, it's not clear to me if, and if so, how, you are closing your database resources. E.g. the result sets never seem to get closed. This could cause resource leaks. However this is incidental to the question (and relies on knowing how your `DBManager` class is implemented), so I won't address it here.